# CFZip of certain file type

Tags: coldfusion, cfzip

Is it possible to use cfzip to create a zip folder containing of a certain type. I need to do this to take out .bak files from a folder with different filetypes and insert them into a zip folder.

Thanks

Colin

Comment: http://help.adobe.com/livedocs/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/help.html?content=Tags_u-z_5.html Shows an example of the delete action with the filter attribute to delete certain extensions.  Or when you create the zip file you can use the filter attribute to only zip files of a certain type and omit the ones you dont want

Comment: @steve - Those are sound suggestions, particularly the latter. You should post that as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Steve already pointed you to the CF documentation which has example of delete. To create a zip, the simplest way is as follows:

```
<cfset fileName = createUUID() />
<cfzip file="D:\#fileName#.zip" action="zip" 
       source="D:\myfolder" 
       filter="*.bak" 
       recurse="No" >
```

If you want to add the files of a sub-directory, then make `recurse="yes"`. To filter multiple file types you can simply use comma separated file type in filter like this `filter="*.jpg, *.gif, *.png"`

Note:  I have used dynamic file name in case you want to run this script multiple times and have different file name, or multiple users are accessing this script at the same time.